# How to imitate the operation law of vector

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector

Given that $(a \times b) \cdot c=2$, now I need to find the value of $[(a+b) \times(b+c)] \cdot(c+a)$.

```
$Assumptions = (a | b | c) ∈ Vectors[3];
Cross[a + b, b + c].(c + a) // ExpandAll
Cross[a + b, b + c].(c + a) // TensorReduce
Solve[Cross[a, b].c == 2 && 
  s == Cross[a + b, b + c].(c + a) && (a | b | c) ∈ 
   Vectors[3], s, {a, b, c}]
```

However, the above code cannot expand or simplify this formula according to the operation rules.

```
a = {x1, y1, z1};
b = {x2, y2, z2};
c = {x3, y3, z3};
Eliminate[{f == Cross[a + b, b + c].(c + a), Cross[a, b].c == 2}, {a, 
  b, c, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3}]
```

I want to know what I can do to simplify this formula like the reference answer and **find its value according to the known conditions**.

**Reference answer:**

$$\begin{array}{l}
{[(a+b) \times(b+c)] \cdot(c+a)} \\
=[(a+b) \times b] \cdot(c+a)+[(a+b) \times c] \cdot(c+a) \\
=(a+b) \times c+(b \times c) \cdot a \\
=(a \times b) \cdot c+(a \times b) \cdot c=4
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Assumptions = (a | b | c) ∈ Vectors[3]
    Cross[a + b, b + c].(c + a) // TensorReduce

(* Simplify[Cross[a + b, b + c].(c + a) // TensorReduce, 
 Assumptions -> a\[Cross]b.c == 2] *)
```